# Modify loops in the same node

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, loops

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,bending,automata,positioning,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4cm,on grid]
  \node[state] (c) {id};
  \node[state] (a) [above left of= c] {$a$};
  \node[state] (b) [above right of= c] {$b$};
  \path[->] (a) edge [bend right=40] node[above right] {$(0,1)$} (c);
  \path[->] (a) edge [bend left=40] node[below left] {$(1,2)$} (c);
  \path[->] (a) edge [bend right= 55] node[below left] {$(2,3)$} (c);
  \path[->] (a) edge [bend left= 55] node[above right] {$(3,0)$} (c);
  \path[->] (b) edge [bend right=20] node[above] {$(0,0)$} (a);
  \path[->] (b) edge [] node[above left] {$(1,1)$} (c);
  \path[->] (b) edge [bend right= 40] node[above] {$(2,2)$} (a);
  \path[->] (b) edge [loop right] node[right] {$(3,3)$} ();
  \path[->] (c) edge [loop below] node[below] {$(0,0)$} ();
  \path[->] (c) edge [in=240,out=290,loop] node[below] {$(1,1)$} ();
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

How can I increase the size of the second loop?

Comment: Can you please make this into a minimal compilable example? So people haven't to guess the needed libraries and the definition of unknown commands.

Comment: @egreg I apologize. I've been update my question

Comment: No need to apologize! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,bending,automata,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4cm,on grid]
   \node[state] (c) {id};
   \node[state] (a) [above left of= c] {$a$};
   \node[state] (b) [above right of= c] {$b$};
   \path[->] (a) edge [bend right=40] node[above right] {$(0,1)$} (c);
   \path[->] (a) edge [bend left=40] node[below left] {$(1,2)$} (c);
   \path[->] (a) edge [bend right= 55] node[below left] {$(2,3)$} (c);
   \path[->] (a) edge [bend left= 55] node[above right] {$(3,0)$} (c);
   \path[->] (b) edge [bend right=20] node[above] {$(0,0)$} (a);
   \path[->] (b) edge [] node[above left] {$(1,1)$} (c);
   \path[->] (b) edge [bend right= 40] node[above] {$(2,2)$} (a);
   \path[->] (b) edge [loop right] node[right] {$(3,3)$} ();
   \path[->] (c) edge [loop below] node[below] {$(0,0)$} ();
   \path[->] (c) edge [scale=5,in=240,out=300,loop] node[below] {$(1,1)$} ();
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This codes produce what I wanted, but complies with an error.

Comment: I fixed the error, which was not in your code. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe someone comes up with a more elegant solution.